# Cannot open ports on Cisco 1841 NAT router

Tags: networking

I have configured PNAT on my router. Everything seems fine.
I have static NAT set for port forwarding for servers behind the NAT router.

I have setup ACLs to open the ports that are being forwarded on the Ext. Interface

but when I do a port scan, only ssh is open, the rest of the ports are closed.

Does any one have an idea as to why this is so?
Thx

Below is the Conf:

```
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
!
hostname OME-GW
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
!
dot11 syslog
ip source-route
!
!
!
!
ip cef
no ip bootp server
ip domain name *******
ip name-server [x.x.x.x]
ip name-server [x.x.x.x]
ip name-server 8.8.8.8
ip name-server 8.8.4.4
no ipv6 cef
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
license udi pid CISCO1841 sn XXXXXX

!
redundancy
!
!
ip ssh port 22 rotary 1
!
class-map match-all win_kasp_updates_allow
 match protocol http url "/.geo.kaspersky.com"
 match protocol http url "/.windowsupdate.com"
 match protocol http url "/update.windows.com"
 match protocol http url "/windowsupdate.microsoft.com"
 match protocol http url "/downloads4.kaspersky-labs.com"
 match access-group 10
class-map match-all everything_else
 match any
!
!
policy-map win_kasp_updates_allow_policy
 class win_kasp_updates_allow
   drop
 class everything_else
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.21 255.255.255.0
 ip access-group 103 in
 ip flow ingress
 ip flow egress
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 !
 service-policy input win_kasp_updates_allow_policy
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address [Public_IP] 255.255.255.252
 ip access-group 102 in
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 !
!
interface Serial0/1/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 no fair-queue
 clock rate 2000000
 !
!
interface Serial0/1/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 clock rate 2000000
 !
!
ip default-gateway [ISP_P2P_IP]
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip flow-export version 5
ip flow-export destination 192.168.1.151 9991
ip flow-top-talkers
 top 10
 sort-by bytes
!
ip dns server
ip nat inside source list 1 interface FastEthernet0/1 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.20 25 [Public_IP] 25 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.20 25 [Public_IP] 26 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.20 53 [Public_IP] 53 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.1.20 53 [Public_IP] 53 extendable
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.1.20 110 [Public_IP] 110 extendable
ip nat inside source static udp 192.168.1.20 1194 [Public_IP] 1194 extendable
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [ISP_P2P_IP]
!
access-list 1 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 10 deny   192.168.1.22
access-list 10 permit 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 102 permit tcp any any eq pop3
access-list 102 permit tcp any any eq smtp
access-list 102 permit tcp any any eq 1194
access-list 102 permit udp any any
access-list 102 permit tcp any any
access-list 102 permit icmp any [ISP_P2P_IP] 0.0.0.3 echo
access-list 102 permit icmp any [ISP_P2P_IP] 0.0.0.3 echo-reply
access-list 102 deny   ip host 195.154.109.72 any
access-list 102 deny   ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.255.255 any
access-list 102 deny   ip 172.16.0.0 0.15.255.255 any
access-list 102 deny   ip 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
access-list 102 deny   ip 127.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
access-list 102 deny   ip 255.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 any
access-list 102 deny   ip 224.0.0.0 31.255.255.255 any
access-list 102 deny   ip host 0.0.0.0 any
access-list 103 deny   ip host 192.168.1.9 any
access-list 103 deny   ip host 192.168.1.35 any
access-list 103 permit ip any any
access-list 103 permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
access-list 103 permit udp host 192.168.1.26 eq domain any
access-list 103 permit tcp host 192.168.1.26 eq domain any
access-list 103 permit udp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
no cdp run

!
!
!
!
snmp-server community secret RO 90
!
!
control-plane
 !
!

!
line con 0
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 exec-timeout 5 0
 login local
 rotary 1
 transport input ssh
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
end
```

Comment: ports are not "opened" on a router, they are "Opened" on a server by an application. They are "unblocked" or "translated" on a router. In order for a port to be open, a server must run a service whose code estabilshes a port for IO, and the expected clients must have an accessible pathway to the port (thats where router forwarding comes in). confirm that you have a serivce running on the port, and that that service is bound to a LAN interface for incoming connections (this is especially important for linux servers).

Comment: Thank you Frank. The scenario is that I previously had an internet facing Linux server with all the services running just fine. Now I have decided to have the server behind a router but still have it servicing these services. So, yes the ports are open and the server is listening on these ports

Comment: so you have confirmed that you have port forwarding rules, and your WAN inbound filter allows packets on those ports (with no state annotation) and that they occur before the default drop rule, or any other drop rules that may catch the traffic? how are you scanning the ports? GCR's shieldsUp or canyouseeme.org?

Comment: I have port forwarding rules. I have  an ACL for each port inbound on the WAN interface allowed before the explicit deny. And I am using http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ to scan for open ports

Comment: Thank you Frank for your time on this one. I managed to resolve the issue, problem was with the default gateway of my server running the services behind the router. I still had it pointing to my old ISP. Problem solved.

Comment: Good. I spent some time reviewing your config, and I feel better now, knowing that the problem was only visible in redacted info. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue, problem was with the default gateway of my server running the services behind the router. I still had it pointing to my old ISP. Problem solved